# use Glimpse to remote debug user issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I want to use Glimpse on a remote server to help a customers when they are off site. I have look up Glimpse Doc to learn more, but I couldn't find any code base about this.

I have read the Glimpse Doc about this topic, but I only able to see my usage and call I request it from local. How can I show other user's usage info in my Glimpse window?
Doc info: 
http://getglimpse.com/Docs/History-Tab

in Web.config

```
    <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Debug.axd">
    <inspectors> 
    <ignoredTypes> 
      <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.DependencyInjectionInspector, Glimpse.Mvc4" /> 
    </ignoredTypes> 
  </inspectors>
      <runtimePolicies>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
      </ignoredTypes>
    </runtimePolicies>
      <!-- 
          For more information on how to configure Glimpse, please visit http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration
          or access {your site}/Glimpse.axd for even more details and a Configuration Tool to support you. 
      -->
    </glimpse>
    <location path="Debug.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

in Custom "GlimpseSecurityPolicy.cs"

```
    public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
    {
        return RuntimePolicy.On;
    }
    public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn
    {
        // The RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource is only needed in case you create a security policy
        // Have a look at http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/12/09/protect-glimpse-axd-with-your-custom-runtime-policy/ for more details
        //RuntimeEvent.EndRequest | 
        get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest | RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource; }
    }
    public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOff
    {
        get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest; }
    }
```

Comment: The history tab shows all requests, including other users, as long as your security permissions are tracking those users. What does your policy configuration look like?

Comment: Here is my code, thanks for your help, also I use and without !httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin") check in my custom GlimpseSecurityPolicy